# What does the parameter "true" mean in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What does the parameter "true" mean in moment.js? For instance:

```
moment("2010-10-31a", ["YYYY-MM-DD"], true).isValid();
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate Could not find there such

Comment: @enot: An important part of our jobs as programmers is learning to thoroughly consume documentation. In this case, it's [not really all that hard to find this information](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Yes, it could be even easier (I've often thought that about Moment docs), but they *are* thorough, just verbose. (A bit like me.)

Answer (score 12):

Note under `String + Format` in the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), down the page a bit, there's the line:

> As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly, including delimeters.

Since it was obvious it was under the `String + Format` section (because that's where it shows the `moment` method signatures), I just navigated to there on the page, then searched  for "boolean". Sure enough, that brought me to the part above.

Answer (score 2):

The third argument of this function indicates whether or not strict mode should be applied to parse the date string:

> Strict mode requires the input to the moment to exactly match the specified format, including separators. Strict mode is set by passing true as the third parameter to the moment function.

In forgiving mode, parsing might still be possible when the date string varies slightly, while in strict mode, the string must respect the correct format. Have a look here: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/